# Restcom Sip Servlets Handle/Detect Disconnected Sip / WebRTC Clients

Tags: java, webrtc, sip, restcomm, simplewebrtc

I've found topic about it here :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobicents-public/disconnect/mobicents-public/B3RcMIkcdxs/Scn7bKpLTvIJ

but I have question.

Is it required to use Restcomm Media to handle/detect disconnected SIP Clients/ WebRTC Clients ?

I use only Sip Servlets only which is tomcat : mss-3.1.633-apache-tomcat-7.0.64
I thought that "SipConnectorListener" will be a solution but no success.

And if I can't handle disconnection event, Is it possible and how to detect that client which is saved into SipServlet's session is valid or not ?

Is there any example about it ?

Regards,
Paata Lominadze.